# How to store lots of user uploaded files in Asp.net in load balanced hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm building a Asp.net site where users can upload files into their user account and then download them whenever they are logged in.  The files will typically be less than 5MB and users can only download the files that they have uploaded (i.e can't download someone else's file).  There are around 100k users and each could potentially upload around 2 or 3 files.  The live site is load balanced

I'm thinking that storing these files in the central  DB (Sql Server) as a BLOB would be nice because...

- As the site is load balanced, each node can access the file from the central DB. No need to worry about having shared folder to store the files
- I can more easily ensure that user's only download their own files.
- Backing up the DB automatically includes the file BLOBS

Only downside to this I've read is performance, but how bad can this be?

If I were to store these files in the file system, would there be any problem storing it all in one folder?

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it fast, then store the data to the filesystem. In this case you dont need to read the amount of data from the sql server. In this case you could do two things:

1st approach: Store all files in one single folder (NTFS limit: 4,294,967,295, FAT limit: 268,435,437)

2nd approach: Create for each user (userid) a separate subfolder. i would prefer this over the 1st approach.

With newer versions of SQL Server you can also use [FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg471497(v=sql.120).aspx).

It would be also interesting to knew

- How many users do you have
- how many uploads per day/hour/minute could you have
- how many downloads per day/hour/minute could you have
- how many uploads at the same time could you have
- how many downloads at the same time could you have
- what is the size of the systems you have
- is it internally used/externally - which bandwidth/network load do you have etc.